# Composite C1 - CMS web interface - unreliable

Tags: c1-cms

I am generally very pleased with Composite C1.

However, I find the web interface a bit unreliable. Even if running locally I have to frequently re-open pages because I can no longer type into the editor - or when I click save it doesn't work (re-opening always fixes the issue).

This happens both in Chrome on Windows & Mac.

Is this a common issue? Why is it so unreliable & is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: 1. What version is you Composite C1? 2. What is your setup like - Web server? OS? .NET Framework version - 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1? XML or SQL-based website? Razor- , Master Pages- or XML-based templates etc

Comment: Was on Windows 8 - now 8.1 with IIS. Use Chrome & Safari on Mac (ML & now Mavericks) and Windows. Same in all of the above.

It also happens when editing on my Window 2012 server on all of the above browsers.

v: 4.0.4897.31550

Razor. It feels like a shortcoming in the window interface system Composite uses (whatever that is - something 'off the shelf' I presume).

You never have this issue?

Comment: I haven't had the issue. That's why I am trying to figure out what might make a difference here